# Authenticating (Team Foundation Server) with impersonalization

Tags: rest, authentication, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I have found how to authenticate to TFS from my app with a given username/password.
I'd like to use the REST services.

```
    public static void BasicAuthRestSample()
    {
        // Create instance of VssConnection using basic auth credentials. 
        // For security, ensure you are connecting to an https server, since credentials get sent in plain text.
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential(username, password))));

        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
        List<QueryHierarchyItem> items = witClient.GetQueriesAsync(teamProjectName).Result;
    }
```

This solution is working fine, but if i create a new workitem, that is created by "username". 
But i want to create workitems by impersonalized users, so i want to see "seconduser" as the creator if i look at the workitem in TFS.

I was googling a lot but can't find an example....

**Update for VSTS:**

After trying to implement i have found this:

"For security reasons (and compliance and a number of other reasons), the impersonation header isn't supported on Visual Studio Online"

A strange thing is that the error message currently misleading, it tells me that I need the special permission while the whole impersonation feature is actually disabled in VSTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [REST API Reference for VS Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview), there is no REST API similar to TFS Impersonation right now. As the .net api still works with VSTS for most features (not support vNext build, etc), you can take the .net api as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`TfsTeamProjectCollection` constructor accepting an `IdentityDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732912%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).
You can find the full explanation in [Introducing TFS Impersonation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2009/12/04/introducing-tfs-impersonation/).

Snippet from the post

`// Get the TFS Identity Management Service
IIdentityManagementService identityManagementService =
            currentUserCollection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
// Look up the user that we want to impersonate
TeamFoundationIdentity identity = identityManagementService.ReadIdentity(
            IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, username, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
TfsTeamProjectCollection impersonatedCollection = 
            new TfsTeamProjectCollection(currentUserCollection.Uri, identity.Descriptor);`

Comment: Thanks, but this is for the SOAP object model, My question was about HttpClients for REST services  ... (The reason we want to use same code for TeamServices also)